# setting the state at the beginning

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

function returns a random string every 10 seconds, I want to set a word from inside the array of strings at the beginning of the function

I tried to set state inside at the start of the life cycle

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        randomItem: 
  this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator()})
    },
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator()})
    }, 10000)
  });
```

-Component

```
class Word extends Component {
state={
    randomItem:''
}

myArray = [
    "esplendor",
    "diciendo",
    "impredecible",
    "problema",
    "terreno",
    "instante",
];

randomItemGenerator = () => (
    this.myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.myArray.length)]
)

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        randomItem: this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator()})
    },
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator()})
    }, 10000)
});




render(){
   return(
      <div><h3>{this.state.randomItem}</h3></div>
   )
}
}
```

is there another lifecycle before componentdidmount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `myArray` and `randomItemGenerator` don't use `props` or other state, you can move the outside of the component, and use them when you initialise the state.

```js
const myArray = [
  "esplendor",
  "diciendo",
  "impredecible",
  "problema",
  "terreno",
  "instante",
]

const randomItemGenerator = () => (
  myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]
)

class Word extends React.Component {
  state = {
    randomItem: randomItemGenerator()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        randomItem: randomItemGenerator()
      })
    }, 10000)
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() { // clear the interval when the component is unmounted
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div><h3>{this.state.randomItem}</h3></div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Word />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However, you might want to get the array of words from props. In this case, change the `randomItemGenerator` to accept an array as it's param, and pass the relevant property (`words` in the example) when you call the function.

```js
const randomItemGenerator = (words) => (
  words[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]
)

class Word extends React.Component {
  state = {
    randomItem: randomItemGenerator(this.props.words)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        randomItem: randomItemGenerator(this.props.words)
      })
    }, 10000)
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() { // clear the interval when the component is unmounted
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div><h3>{this.state.randomItem}</h3></div>
    )
  }
}

const myArray = [
  "esplendor",
  "diciendo",
  "impredecible",
  "problema",
  "terreno",
  "instante",
]

ReactDOM.render(
   <Word words={myArray} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your function in the state initialization:

```
class Word extends Component {
    state = {
        randomItem: this.randomItemGenerator()
    }
```

Comment: TypeError: this.randomItemGenerator is not a function,  I move the function before state but it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'minutes' of null

Comment: I don't see any minutes property access in your code. Would you share a codepen with your updated code?